# How to pass the parameter of type Class<T[]> java

Tags: java, generics

Playing with [QueryDSL](http://www.querydsl.com/static/querydsl/4.0.5/apidocs/com/querydsl/core/types/Projections.html#array-java.lang.Class-com.querydsl.core.types.Expression...-) library.

Found interesting function

```
public static <T> ArrayConstructorExpression<T> array(Class<T[]> type, Expression... exprs)
```

I've never seen such a Generic as mentioned above. How can I pass the first parameter there?

Googling last hour, but no result for now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming `T` is of class `Integer`, you can do as follows:

```
ArrayConstructorExpression<Integer> arr = array(Integer[].class, someExpression);
```

There's no magic here. `Integer[].class` is the class that represents arrays of `Integer` objects.

Comment: Cool thanks! Was really hard to search for it, because google ignores square brackets.

Comment: @SanatSerikuly Glad it helped